# Adding persistence to multiboot USB made with YUMI

Tags: usb, partitioning, bootable-media, persistence

I recently made a multiboot USB with YUMI. I've only put the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Kali on it so I can use the stick on systems that run either a 32 bit or 64 bit OS. I actually have a macbook pro that has a 64 bit processor and an Acer laptop that has a 32 bit processor, and I wanted to run Kali on both of these machines.

I've only run the 32 bit OS on the Acer so far, and everything works great except I can't get the persistence to work. I thought all I had to do was choose the "Live USB Persistence" option, but after some googling I'm under the impression that I need to add a partition to the USB for storage. I don't see a way to do that from YUMI, though.

Is there a way to do this outside of a Linux system? Can I do this without making a live CD of Ubuntu? I really don't want to make one JUST so I can use GParted. Is there something else I need to do because this is a multiboot USB, or because I used YUMI to make it? I'm open to downloading an application on Windows Vista (it's an older Acer) or on OSX.

Am I completely wrong about what I think I have to do to make Kali persistent? Am I overlooking something? Any advice would be appreciated.

***EDIT***
Also, once persistence is working, I'd like to use a single space to store things for both the 32 and 64 bit versions of Kali, preferably in a space larger than 4GB. It's on a FAT32 file system so I know about the 4GB limit. I've read that it's possible with casper -rw partitions, but I don't know it's feasible because of the ways the operating systems are processed. If I need to make 2 separate spaces it's ok, just less convenient if I want to add the same documents or applications to both Kalis.

Comment: On behalf of Thomas: What did you do for working persistence on usb multiboot drive(YUMI)? Did you use this procedure https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBzx5rAc4V4?

Comment: I saw his question below. I think there was a misunderstanding. My question is also on how to get persistence on Kali with YUMI. I have a lot more details in my question, but that's essentially it.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to boot another *nix OS (not the one with the stick you want to use) and use gparted or something like that to manually partition the USB stick (I had to first resize the current partition to make space). 
Create a new primary ext4 partition labeled "persistence". Kali is preconfigured to use that label so this is important.
Mount the new partition and create in the root a file named "persistence.conf" and add just one line: "/ union".

That's all. I tried that and worked, you just have to boot kali in yumi using the persistence option.

Comment: Is it only Kali that can use the "persistence" label?